# Problems with pandas boxplot showing points on it

Tags: python, pandas

I am plotting a box plot with se following code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
plt.title("Title")
plt.ylabel('Y-ax')
boxplot = df.boxplot(grid=False, rot=90, fontsize=10)  

plt.show()
```

And I get this plot:

[image: plot]

Is there any way I can just show like the normal boxplot with the 50/75/90 percentiles and not those circles that I have no clue what do they mean?

The data frame is huge, maybe that is why these points are shown?

Comment: Try adding `showfliers=False` and `whis=(10, 90)`. Also it might help to read [`boxplot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html) to see the boxplot properties.